# Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'xxx' after .NET 4.5.1 Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

We have Win2k8 servers running 4000 .NET 4.0 websites fine. We've put off the Framework update for as long as we can, and are running into issues with __dopostback() with browser detection, that we can't work around any longer.

I cloned one of our servers (VM) and installed just the .NET 4.5.1 update Okay.

The problem we now have, is that the behavior of 4.5.1 seems to have changed with regards to throwing exceptions for DLL references that are in a module, but NOT uploaded to the server.

For example, we have a Support.DLL that has dotless.core.dll as a reference. This is only used in a windows service (that references the support.dll), but is never used in the web applications, so the dotless.core.dll has never been uploaded (and shouldn't be) to the websites.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = dotless.Core, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96b446c9e63eae34
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/root/2362/Sites/3168/Site/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\root\2362\Sites\3168\Site\bin
Calling assembly : Support, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
```

The .NET 4.0 framework never complained, and simply ignored these missing references. There are no references in web.configs.

If I uninstall the 4.5.1 framework update, the problem goes away. So this does appear to be a behavior change in the update.  Is there a registry/machine.config option to disable this new behavior?

Not ideal, but putting this DLL into the GAC resolves the problem, but we don't want to start copying DLLs to the servers when they are never used.

We have nearly 4000 websites that will be affected when the 4.5.1 update is applied. Part of the reason we've not done the updates for so long.  Never as straightforward as MS would like us to believe!

Many thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: Why is .svcmap in the title?

Comment: Because that was the Exception that was being thrown. Should have put quotes around the text:

Answer (score 0):

You can actually fix the root cause because there is a hotfix for the browser detection problem: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

MSDN says nothing about that changed behavior: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=vs.110%29.aspx . Do you have a stack trace? Maybe some other change in .NET 4.5.1 leads your code to a place in your DLL which references the missing DLL?

I created a small solution, one class library and one console application that references the class library. If you pass an argument to the console application, it calls into the class library, otherwise it doesn't. I compiled it and deleted the class library DLL. Results: when I passed the argument, it complaint that it cannot load the assembly, otherwise there weren't any problems at all. The reference loading only takes place when you actually enter a method that references it. So I don't think there is any new behavior in this respect.